# Extracting values out of multi-dimenrional array php

Tags: php

I'm using CURL with multiple requests which outputs multi-dimensional array. I need to extract 3 of the values from the output (url , content_type, and http_code ) then assign each to a new array separately i.e.  `$array1=url $array2=content_type $array3=http_code.`

I tried to use a for statement to extract each of the values but that didn't work as expected, I got

> " Undefined offset:"
>
> Array output
>
> Array ( [http://example1/] => Array ( [url] => http://example1/
>   [content_type] => [http_code] => 405 [header_size] => 249
>   [request_size] => 48 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0
>   [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.328 [namelookup_time] => 0
>   [connect_time] => 0.172 [pretransfer_time] => 0.172 [size_upload] => 0
>   [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0
>   [download_content_length] => 0 [upload_content_length] => -1
>   [starttransfer_time] => 0.328 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] =>
>   [primary_ip] => 204.79.197.200 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port]
>   => 80 [local_ip] => 192.168.2.12 [local_port] => 55536 ) [http://example2/] => Array ( [url] => http://example2/ [content_type]
>   => text/html; charset=utf-8 [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 699 [request_size] => 57 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0
>   [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.453 [namelookup_time] => 0.015
>   [connect_time] => 0.203 [pretransfer_time] => 0.203 [size_upload] => 0
>   [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0
>   [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1
>   [starttransfer_time] => 0.453 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] =>
>   [primary_ip] => 104.16.34.249 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port]
>   => 80 [local_ip] => 192.168.2.12 [local_port] => 55539 ) )

```
for($y=0;$y<= (count($array1)-1);$y++){
      echo $array1 [$y][0][1][2];
  }
```

Comment: Could you please format the code properly? Additionally, what kind of output is this (commas missing) ?

Comment: That's not my code, its the output of print_r. I have a function that uses multiple curls which output the result above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get this:

```
$array1 = [
    'content_type' => ['', 'text/html; charset=utf-8']
];

$array2 = [
    'url' => ['http://example1/', 'http://example2/']
];

$array3 = [
    'http_code' => [405, 200]
];
```

Then try to use `foreach` loop.

```
foreach ($output as $url => $values) {
    $array1['content_type'][] = $values['content_type'];
    $array2['url'][] = $values['url'];
    $array3['http_code'][] = $values['http_code'];
}
```

Read more about [`foreach` loop](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [`Array` type](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Also in associative arrays you can't get values using numeric indexes, there strings instead of.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I've never used multi-dimensional/associative arrays array before so it was a bit of a challenge. I need to learn more about it.